# Pedal: Platform came off axle which remained in crank

Tags: pedals, bearings

I have Shimano PD-T780 pedals. I bought them almost new only a year ago and they aren't cheap pedals.

[image: Shimano PD-T780]

On one pedal, the platform suddenly came off, revealing an axle which tapers off towards its end and has threads at that end barely visible through the grease in the following picture:
[image: 2 parts]

The axle thing has a hex indentation on the side not visible in the picture which is used to screw it into the crank. The silver wrench ring (like a nut but no screw threads visible) attached to the platform is labelled "Tighten 10Nm" and I haven't ever turned it. I don't  know what it's for. Looking into the platform, I think bearing balls were visible. Maybe it's designed to come apart like this for servicing.

[image: 2 parts other view]

Here is an exploded view: [I can't seem to upload the picture I extracted from this pdf.](https://www.paul-lange.de/index.php/de/explosionszeichnungen.html?file=files/paullange/07_Service/04_Downloads/Shimano/explosionszeichnungen/PD/PD-T780_3196A.pdf) The two leftmost pieces of assembly 1 (the ring is rubber, a seal I guess) are on the crank, the other pieces are in the platform.

I was in something of a hurry, so I just stuck it back on and used another bicycle.

How do I properly reassemble this? And while I'm at it, should I add some grease?

Comment: Add a picture showing the damaged pedal if you can easily take it back off again. It's a little unclear to me from your description what exactly happened.

Comment: @SSilk Braved the rain to take two pictures. :)

Comment: In the first picture of your pedal (so the middle pic), there's the silver collar for a wrench to seat on, and it says "Tighten" on the side. Not sure if that's intended to be the main tightening point for the pedal to go into the crankarm, or for removing the pedal platform from the axel, as has happened to you. Does the end of the pedal axel (which is currently threaded into the crankarm) also have an Allen key (hexagonal) spot for tightening it? How did you tighten the pedal onto your crankarm? With the wrench location out by the platform, or hex location at the other end of the axel?

Comment: PS: If you look at the instructions for this pedal, it points out the hex location at the end of the axel that I mentioned, and says to use that to install them. If makes no mention of the silver wrench collar out by the pedal platform which makes me think you're not supposed to use that for this purpose. http://si.shimano.com/pdfs/si/SI-46P0A-001-ENG.pdf

Comment: @SSilk To mount/remove the pedal there is a hexagonal indentation on the other side of the crank. The "Tighten" wrench collar is not used for that and I have never turned it.

Comment: I found an exploded view: https://www.paul-lange.de/index.php/de/explosionszeichnungen.html?file=files/paullange/07_Service/04_Downloads/Shimano/explosionszeichnungen/PD/PD-T780_3196A.pdf Still looking at it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a component diagram for these pedals [here](https://www.paul-lange.de/index.php/de/explosionszeichnungen.html?file=files/paullange/07_Service/04_Downloads/Shimano/explosionszeichnungen/PD/PD-T780_3196A.pdf).

Here's the main diagram:

[image]

Looks like all the bearings are mounted onto the axle and secured with a bearing preload and lock nut at the outboard end. The axle and bearing assembly is then threaded into the pedal using the threads on part 2 - that's why the torque spec is printed on its shoulder.

Obviously the retaining nuts came undone. All the balls, cones, bushings and nuts should still be in the pedal body as part 2 should have stopped them from falling out.

If you un-thread part 2 you can get all the balls, cones, bushings and retaining nuts out. I'd do this over a tray or box to catch the balls and small parts that will fall out. You can then reassemble the bearings and, then thread the assembly back into the pedal body.

You could try re-inserting the axle, un-threading part 2 and see if you can withdraw the bearings etc on the axle.

Update:

You should examine the state of the bearings and cones to make sure they are OK before proceeding with reassembly. Maybe something seized which caused the retaining nuts to come undone.

Comment: Nice one, style points: should they add any grease?

Comment: @Swifty There appears to be quite a lot of grease on the axle, but  to re-assemble the bearing the OP will probably need to clean some off and add more as needed.

Comment: @Swifty Actually, as I think about it, If I were doing this I'd clean all the grease off as its contaminated with water and probably dirt, use complete new fresh grease, AND disassemble and service the other pedal in case it's also  about to fall apart too.

Comment: At 1 year old, I suggest its faulty manufacturing and the OP should talk to the seller as a first option (Depends on local laws and where/how they were purchased).

Comment: @mattnz That was unlucky, how you wrote an answer while AA wrote an answer while I had just found the schematics.

Comment: I'm going to take it apart, clean the grease off and check if it's broken. If yes I'll contact the seller. He is too far away to go complain in person (more expensive than pedals), but maybe he'll agree to send me replacements if I show him pictures of the broken ones. There might be warranty if it's a manufacturing defect.

Comment: @mattnz. That's valid. A good LBS that sold these *might* reassemble the pedal for free or at least at discount. Returning or warranty claim is probably a long shot as pedals look well used.

Comment: Although it was slightly more than a year, so probably no warranty.

Comment: I just noticed the tip of the axle is broken off - it has an unusual rough ending and the screw part is only half as long as in the diagram. And even though it's perfectly possible to take it apart, I assume there are no repair parts available.

Comment: @Nobody That sucks. Pedals are a current offering so an axle might not be impossible to get hold of.

Comment: The axle being hardened steel it may break. You could get a replacement axle but it will probably be as expensive as a new pedal. Getting a new set might be a better alternative. Use the undamaged one after servicing as a spare in case of another mishap. And there are salvageable bits on the broken one. Pedals like cassette are consumables!

Comment: @Carel Good brands do offer replacements spindles and bearing sets for their pedals.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not this easy. The bearing cups are press fit into the pedal body by the silver collar. You can’t really remove it recoverably (see the suggestion to use a tap): https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/71777/why-aren-t-these-shimano-pd-m980-coming-apart

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be a common problem with this otherwise fine Shimano pedal: the outside end of the axle broke off. (Because of an excessively tightened nut!?!) Had the same thing happen to me some time ago. Shimano (Paul Lange) claimed I had caused the damage when "servicing the pedal"...

Replacement axles are available in the aftermarket.  But this only works if you are able to remove the outside cone and retaining nut from the inside of the pedal body.