# Why aren’t these Shimano PD-M980 coming apart?

Tags: shimano, spd

I’m trying to give my pedals a clean and regrease. The left pedal came apart as expected, but the right one’s threaded sleeve refuses to separate from the pedal body. I’ve unthreaded it as much as I can, but the spindle still hasn’t separated. Trying to further loosen the sleeve just results in it spinning within the pedal body. Has anyone experienced this before? How do you fix it? I’m considering using some bolts to act as a press, ripping the few remaining threads off.

[image]

Edit: Here’s a comparison with the internals of the left pedal. I’m not sure how the sleeve got shoved so far up the spindle. As you can see, there’s not that many threads remaining, so I don’t think forcefully ripping the sleeve out would cause too much damage.

Furthermore, when I try to remove the stuck right pedal, I can’t feel the thread doing anything. Usually when you try to remove a bolt after it’s all the way out already, you can feel the bolt climb a little bit before dropping down again. It’s hard to explain. Here, it feels like I’m just turning a round peg in a round hole. I can’t detect any climb-drop behavior.

[image]

Comment: I'd start by taking all the clamp and platform parts off with a 5mm? hex tool.  There may be additional fastners below which are already broken in your other pedal.
Can you afford to replace them?  If not, force is not yet a good idea.  Might be better to flush the bearings however you can, then dry and regrease without separating them ?

Comment: @Criggie All Shimano pedals have the same basic design. The spindle goes in a plain hole, there’s nothing protruding into it. I recently bought these used for cheap and the bearings need to be tightened, which is arguably a bigger problem than relubricating them (hence the low price). I’ve sprayed the area with penetrating oil, it surely can’t hurt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved! I realized that the sleeve should not be able to press itself up the spindle like it did in photo #2. I clamped a set of vice grip pliers between the sleeve and the spindle’s flange to stop it from press-fitting itself into the spindle. It came out after that. I will inspect the whole assembly for damage since the hardened steel spindle is significantly larger than the aluminum sleeve.

Edit:

To conclude this saga, the bearing disassembled itself while still pressed into the pedal body, which is terminal. There is no way to remove the bearing cup, which was supposed to be press-fit in and out via the black threaded sleeve. It was worth a try though!

Comment: Thank you for the closure.   On the plus side, new gear shopping !  Downside, you have to pay for them.

Comment: If you have the axle out but other parts of the bearing remain in the pedal body, they can still be removed. I did this last time using a tap, I think, though it was a couple of years ago. You would need a new axle assembly however.  When I managed this with some old xtr pedals, I found something the right diameter to tap into the sleeve and it had enough engagement to pull the sleeve out. I think it was the knurled handle of my tap/die set. I now have a blind bearing puller set which makes these jobs a lot more straightforward.

Comment: @JoeK Just saw this now. I got these for $25, a new spindle set really wasn’t worth it. Stripped the unworn bits off, swapped them with the worn pieces on my current PD-M985, and resold them for $20 :)